# regular expression to validate ssn for one format

Tags: c#, regex

I have constructed regular expression to validate ssn for the following
invalid formats - all **repeated** number 0 to 9.
For example : **000000000**, **1111111111** and so on till **999999999** or with **hyphens** 000-00-0000. with some other invalid formats 1-9 sequence and 9-1 sequence with and without hyphens.

I would like to include **reg-ex** for **111-22-3333** and **111223333** as invalid to the **below reg-ex.**

Any quick suggestions please.

**reg-ex:**  "^(?!123([ -]?)45([ -]?)6789)(?!\b(\d)\3+\b)(?!000|666|9)[0-9]{3}([ -]?)(?!00)[0-9]{2}\4(?!0000)[0-9]{4}$"

Reg-ex is working for all formats I needed. I would need to add only for 111-22-3333 and without hyphens.

Comment: Repeated digit SSNs are probably valid. Just about any number at or above "001-01-0001" can be a valid SSN. There are no existing SSNs that start with "9" right now. That's very handy to know for creating test identities. A few jobs ago (in an SSN-heavy business), each of us reserved blocks of invalid SSNs fir our tests. Mine all started with 987

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-validate-ssn-social-security-number-using-regular-expression/

Comment: i honestly think that you are better off explicitly testing for those 'well known' invalid values. Look at that regex, nobody will be able to work out its intent

Comment: `^[0-8][0-9]{2}(?<!000|666)-?([0-9][1-9])|([1-9][0-9])-?([1-9][0-9]{3})|([0-9]{3}[1-9])$`: technically, `111-22-3333` are valid SSN; https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/regular-expressions-cookbook/9781449327453/ch04s12.html

Comment: @DmitryBychenko 
 sorry to update ..it didnot work.

Comment: Social Security Number (SSN) validation is actually more complicated than this in reality.

Comment: Examples: SSA will not issue SSNs beginning with the number “9”.
 SSA will not issue SSNs beginning with the number “666” in positions 1 – 3.
 SSA will not issue SSNs beginning with the number “000” in positions 1 – 3.
 SSA will not issue SSNs with the number “00” in positions 4 – 5.
 SSA will not issue SSNs with the number “0000” in positions 6 – 9.

Comment: Regexs are very powerful, but the regex in your question is very hard to understand. Complex regexs are hard to maintain and hard to understand. Adding extra checks into it will make it even more complex and even harder to maintain in the future. I suggest using several smaller regexs and some C# code to select between them.

Answer (score 1):

Since your regex already forbids same digit first block, `111-22-3333` and `111 22 3333` are of the table.

To exclude `111223333` you can simply add one more negative lookahead in the beginning:

```
^(?!111223333)(?!123([ -]?)45([ -]?)6789)(?!\b(\d)\3+\b)(?!000|666|9)[0-9]{3}([ -]?)(?!00)[0-9]{2}\4(?!0000)[0-9]{4}$
```

Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/3lVJ4N/1).

Comment: thank you for posting the solution. The following pattern is working

"^(?!111223333)(?!111-22-3333)(?![^0-9]*([0-9])(?:[^0-9]*\\1)*[^0-9]*$)(?!123([ -]?)45([ -]?)6789)(?!000|666|9)[0-9]{3}([ -]?)(?!00)[0-9]{2}\\4(?!0000)[0-9]{4}$"